# Test if another method was called

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

So I'm sure there is something like this out there but I have been searching for an hour and haven't found exactly what I am looking for. say I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void myMethod(boolean shouldCallOtherMethod)
    {
        if(shouldCallOtherMethod)
        {
            otherMethod();
        }
    }

    public void otherMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Called");
    }
}
```

How do I make something like this work?

```
@Test
public void shouldCallMethod()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.myMethod(true)

    // verify myClass.otherMethod method was called
}
```

Comment: Your task is not clear at all.

Comment: public boolean myMethod(){}                                      if(myMethod()==true){
    //do task
}
else {
    //do task
}

Comment: -1 @PM77-1 comment. CodesLikeA_Monkey's task is very clear: He bluntly states in the title that he wants to test if another method is called. The title has been the same since he posted his question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/), you can do *spying on real objects* like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void otherMethodShouldBeCalled() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        MyClass spy = spy(myClass);

        spy.myMethod(true);
        verify(spy).otherMethod();
    }
}
```

There are some gotchas, so take a look at the [relevant documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) as well.

Comment: It does not work: `Argument passed to verify() is of type ... and is not a mock!`

Answer (score 6):

Suppose `MokeysClass` has a constructor declared like this, where `Foo` is some other class.

```
public MokeysClass(String name, int counter, Foo myFoo)
```

I would write my test like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestArray {
    @Mock 
    private Foo mockMyFoo;
    private String nameToInject = "Mokey";
    private int counterToInject = 42;

    @Spy 
    private MokeysClass toTest = new MokeysClass(nameToInject, counterToInject, mockMyFoo);

    @Test
    public void shouldCallMethod() {
        toTest.myMethod(true);
        verify(toTest).otherMethod();
    }
}
```

so that I am explicitly stating which constructor to call when I create my test object, and what arguments to pass to it.

There are some reasons not to rely on `@InjectMocks` to do this step for me, particularly if the class being tested is more complex and has more than one constructor.  Mockito chooses the constructor that has the most arguments, but if there are several constructors with the same number of arguments, Mockito could choose any of the constructors; that is, the behaviour is undefined.

Once Mockito has chosen a constructor, it checks whether that constructor can in fact be used for constructor injection.  Constructor injection will not be used if

- one or more of the parameters of the chosen constructor is a primitive type,
- the type of one or more of the parameters of the chosen constructor is a final class,
- the type of one or more of the parameters of the chosen constructor is a private class,
- the only constructor of the class is the default constructor.

If any one of these conditions holds, for the constructor that Mockito chose, then constructor injection won’t be used.  In this case, the class must have a default constructor, otherwise Mockito will throw an exception.

The complexity of the criteria which Mockito uses when choosing whether to apply constructor injection implies that adding or removing a constructor, or changing the parameters of a constructor, can make Mockito switch from using constructor injection to using setter and field injection; or from using setter and field injection to using constructor injection.  This can occur even if the constructor that is changed is not the one that will be used for constructor injection.

As a result, any test that uses constructor injection is automatically quite brittle; in the sense that changes that are not directly related to the test itself can cause the test to fail.  Such failures can be difficult to troubleshoot.

The `@InjectMocks` annotation was designed for use with frameworks such as Spring that do dependency injection; and for tests of classes that use Spring, it can be invaluable.  But if dependency injection is not part of your class, I would strongly recommend avoiding `@InjectMocks` on account of its brittleness.  You really want your test code to be as easy to maintain and to troubleshoot as your production code is.

Answer (score 3):

This is **not recommended**, but you can spy real object :)

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Spy
    private MyClass sut; // System Under Test

    @Test
    public void shouldCallMethod() {

        // when
        sut.myMethod(true);

        // then
        verify(sut).otherMethod();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Tests Passed: 1 passed in 0,203 s
```

After changing code: `sut.myMethod(false);`

```
Wanted but not invoked:
sut.otherMethod();
-> at my.custom.MyClassTest.shouldCallMethod(MyClassTest.java:23)
```

Source: [Spying on real objects](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

---

### Magic version with constructor injection

```
@Mock
private LexAnalyzer lexAnalyzer;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private SyntaxAnalyzer sut; // System Under Test

@Test
public void shouldCallMethod() {

    // when
    sut.myMethod(true);

    // then
    verify(sut).otherMethod();
}
```

### `SyntaxAnalyzer.java`

```
public class SyntaxAnalyzer {

    private final LexAnalyzer lexAnalyzer;

    public SyntaxAnalyzer(LexAnalyzer lexAnalyzer) {
        this.lexAnalyzer = lexAnalyzer;
    }
...
```

Tested, works ;)

Comment: what is not ideal here? The second message is when test **should fail**! :) This is simply beautiful!

Comment: Sorry, there's no way you could have known what I meant. My real object has a constructor arg which makes the `@Spy` annotation not work for me.

Comment: no way, `@Spy` loves constructors, show me your code :) Simply use InjectsMocks

Comment: `public SyntaxAnalyzer(LexAnalyzer lexScanner)
 {
  this.lexScanner = lexScanner; }`

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey Sample with constructor injection added :) This is so simple and works ;)

Comment: I see. This is great, thanks so much! I wish I could mark more than one answer!

Comment: You can also write `@Spy private SyntaxAnalyzer sut = new SyntaxAnalyzer( some constructor arguments here );` if you don't want to use `@InjectMocks`.  There are some reasons to avoid using `@InjectMocks` for constructor injection.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But I prefer minimal version until it works :)

Comment: OK, maybe if I have time, I'll post an answer later, along with an explanation of why `@InjectMocks` might be a thing to avoid for this kind of test.

Comment: @DavidWallace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182906/why-injectmocks-might-be-a-thing-to-avoid

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look at Mock objects.  You can create a mock of MyClass, then set expectations that otherMethod() is called when you call myMethod and fails if it was not called.

Here is a pretty good overview of them for java - http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects

One other major benefit of using Mocks, you can avoid side affects, like logging to NSLog or hitting a web server or printing) in your test.

Comment: Also, write JUnit tests that use mocked objects.