# Why Mockito @InjectMocks might be a thing to avoid?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

Why `@InjectMocks` might be a thing to avoid for this kind of test.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private Bar bar;

    @InjectMocks
    private Foo foo; // created by Mockito

    @Test
    public void shouldCallMethod() {

        // when
        foo.myMethod();

        // then
        ...
    }
}
```

### `Foo.java`

```
public class Foo {

    private final Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
...
```

I read about this in comments to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172873/516167

### About @InjectMocks

> Mark a field on which injection should be performed.
>
> - Allows shorthand mock and spy injection.
> - Minimizes repetitive mock and spy injection.

Reference: [@InjectMocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) JavaDoc.

Comment: I've just discovered the magic that `@InjectMocks` has performed and it bothers me. The test was not marked as dependent on Spring in any way, yet dependencies got automatically fulfilled. I couldn't figure out how, so trying to figure out what code I needed to write for a new test was confusing. As one article says - inject your dependencies yourself, don't leave it to non-obvious invisible logic.

Answer (score 2):

The only disadvantage I see is that you have to comply to its rules.
You may have more control if you don't use `@InjectMocks`

From their docs, I added some in **bold**:

> Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection,
>   setter injection, or property injection in order and as described
>   below. If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito **won't
>   report failure**; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.
>
> Constructor injection; **the biggest constructor is chosen**, then
>   arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only. Note: If
>   arguments can not be found, then null is passed. If non-mockable types
>   are wanted, then constructor injection won't happen. In these cases,
>   you will have to satisfy dependencies yourself.
>
> Property setter injection; mocks will first be resolved by type, then,
>   if there is several property of the same type, by the match of the
>   property name and the mock name. Note 1: **If you have properties with
>   the same type (or same erasure), it's better to name all @Mock
>   annotated fields with the matching properties, otherwise Mockito might
>   get confused and injection won't happen.**
>
> Note 2: If @InjectMocks instance wasn't initialized before and have a
>   no-arg constructor, then it will be initialized with this constructor.
>
> Field injection; mocks will first be resolved by type, then, if there
>   is several property of the same type, by the match of the field name
>   and the mock name. Note 1: If you have fields with the same type (or
>   same erasure), it's better to name all @Mock annotated fields with the
>   matching fields, otherwise Mockito might get confused and injection
>   won't happen.
>
> Note 2: If @InjectMocks instance wasn't initialized before and have a
>   no-arg constructor, then it will be initialized with this constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Also, some people sugest that dependencies should be added by constructor, not by setters, this way the correct dependecies are guarantied at compile time. See [this](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/).

By using constructors you are forced to limit yourself in the number of components to use as a dependency reducing complexity. (This may not be easy and changes a lot the way to do things in Spring).

**Update**: After some time working with dependencies autowired in the constructor I have clearly noted that test are less fragile. I still need to change the tests when dependencies change but the compiler tells me where I should change it and how big the change is. Even better, now I can distinguish between changes to the test to adapt to the new code in compile time and failures added by this code in runtime.