# PowerMockito using InjectMocks error

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a very complicated class to write Junit test case. I decided to use PowerMockito since my class for which the test is to be run has a constructor initialization.

My main class is like this:

```
public class MainClass extends BaseClass{

MainClass(SomeClass class){
    super(class);
}

public void methodToBeTested(){
some code here
}

..few other methods which I am not going to test.
}
```

Now I have the test case written like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass{

@Mock
OtherClassUsedInMainClass mock1;

@Mock
OtherClassUsedInMainClass mock2;

@InjectMocks
MainClass mainClass;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(MainClass.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(SomeClass.class))
            .thenReturn(mainClass);)
}

@Test
public void testMethodtobeTested(){
    ...I am using the other objects to mock data and test if this method works fine

    mainClass.methodtobeTested();
    \\This method will increment a value. I am just asserting if that value is right. 
    Assert.assertEquals(mainClass.checkCount(),RequiredCount)

}

}
```

I am getting a **null pointer exception** when running the Testcase since it tries to initialize the **mainClass**. It does not get mocked. I know I am doing something wrong. But I just don't know what it is.

Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'mainClass' of type 'class com.main.MainClass'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
This null pointer exception is thrown from a the constructor of the BaseClass when it tries to initialize another class.
```

Comment: Show the constructor of BaseClass. There you get an error

Comment: Why are you stubbing MainClass? Isn't that the class you are testing?

Comment: @Jens The base class constructor take someClass passed from mainClass as an argument. It also uses this someClass and uses it to initialze few other classes which also has a constructor which uses someClass.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster can you please explain ?

Comment: You should not do anything like `PowerMockito.whenNew(MainClass.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(SomeClass.class)).thenReturn(mainClass);)`. You should be testing against a normal instance of MainClass without any stubbing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks) explains the difference between `@Mock` and  `@InjectMocks`:

`@Mock` creates a mock. `@InjectMocks` creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the `@Mock` (or `@Spy`) annotations into this instance.

`MainClass` constructor expects a `SomeClass` parameter but there isn't any mock for that.

Your code should be something like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass{

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    SomeClass mock1;

    @InjectMocks
    MainClass mainClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
    ...
```

Comment: I did this. But still the code goes into the BaseClass. I get a null pointer  again from the BaseClass when it tries to init.

Comment: @ViChU I expect this is a different and it has something to do with the way base class uses that mock. probably is doing something with the return object from a method from SomeClass. try using @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)

Comment: I tried this. It still throws a null from the BaseClass. When MainClass const calls super(someClass), it calls BaseClass const with someClass. Inside the contructor, there are a few objects created. Some access someClass object while others use someClass in their constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the source code. Anyways I will try other methods and get back.

Comment: Do you really need to invoke `initMocks` if you annotate the test class with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

Comment: @no; probably not; I keep it as original; updated now

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21183623/3788176), which is quoting the [`@InjectMocks` documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

> Constructor injection; the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only. Note: If arguments can not be found, then null is passed.

So, presumably, declare a field of type `SomeClass`, and annotate it `@Mock`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't show us the actual code it is very hard to guess what exactly is happening. But it looks like your mock `SomeClass` needs some stubbed behavior to satisfy the BaseClass constructor.

For example:

```
// the instance of MainClass you run your tests against
private MainClass instance;

@Mock
private SomeClass someClass;
@Mock
private SomethingElse somethingElse;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(someClass.doSomething()).thenReturn(somethingElse);
    instance = new MainClass(someClass);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // SETUP
    when(somethingElse.doWeirdStuff()).thenThrow(new WeirdException());

    // CALL
    instance.performTapDance();

    // VERIFY
    assertTrue(instance.isWeird());
}
```